# Erro com modal usando PartialView Asp Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro no meu projeto:

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the
>   ViewDataDictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[HelpDesk.Models.Fornecedores]', but
>   this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type
>   'HelpDesk.Models.Fornecedores'.

Nesse projeto tenho a seguinte situação, tenho um Index onde carrego uma lista retornada do banco, e nele tenho um botão onde chamo uma modal que esta dentro de uma PartialView com o objetivo de cadastrar novos dados, o problema pelo que consegui entender e que estou tendo **conflito do Index que uso @model IEnumerable com a Partial onde uso @model HelpDesk.Models.Fornecedores.** Gostaria de ajuda como corrigir esse erro, ou se a outro método mais eficiente para ter a mesma solução para esse projeto.

Controller:

```
  public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View( _context.Fornecedores.ToList());
    } 

    public IActionResult NovoFornecedor()
    {
        return PartialView("_NovoFornecedor");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> NovoFornecedor (Fornecedores fornecedores)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(fornecedores);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return PartialView("_NovoFornecedor");
    }
```

Index:

```
@model IEnumerable<HelpDesk.Models.Fornecedores>

    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Cadastro de Fornecedores";
    }

    <div class="container">
        <h4>Fornecedores Cadastrados</h4>
        <p>
            <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#NovoFornecedor">Novo Fornecedor</button>
        </p>
        <div class="table table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Empresa</th>
                        <th scope="col">CNPJ</th>
                        <th scope="col">Responsavel</th>
                        <th scope="col">Celular</th>
                        <th scope="col">Fixo</th>
                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                        <th scope="col">Ações</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Empresa)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CNPJ)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Responsavel)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Celular)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fixo)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)</td>
                            <td>
                                  <a asp-action="EditarFornecedor" asp-route-id="@item.FornecedorId" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm">Atualizar</a> |
                            <a onclick="ModalExcluir (@item.FornecedorId)" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm">Excluir</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    @Html.Partial("_NovoFornecedor")
```

_PartialView

```
@model HelpDesk.Models.Fornecedores

<div class="modal fade" id="NovoFornecedor">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Cadastrar Novo Fornecedor</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Empresa:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Empresa">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">CNPJ:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" asp-for="CNPJ"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua `PartialView` está utilizando a `model` da `View` por padrão:

```
@model IEnumerable<HelpDesk.Models.Fornecedores>
```

Isso ocorre por que você não informou o segundo parâmetro do método `Html.Partial` e na `Partial` está esperando por uma `@model`. Como é um novo fornecedor, pode apenas instanciar um novo objeto:

```
@Html.Partial("_NovoFornecedor", new HelpDesk.Models.Fornecedores())
```